# How can I ensure tests with a marker are only run if explicitly asked in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I have some tests I marked with an appropriate marker. If I run pytest, by default they run, but I would like to skip them by default. The only option I know is to explicitly say "not marker" at pytest invocation, but I would like them not to run by default unless the marker is explicitly asked at command line.

Comment: Seems that the example in [Control skipping of tests according to command line option](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#control-skipping-of-tests-according-to-command-line-option) matches your use case.

Comment: @hoefling no. I don't want to add command line options. I want to run pytest without any command line option and get all tests _except_ those marked, but if I run with -k "marker" I want them (and only them) to be run

Comment: Sure, it's not a copy-and-paste example, you need to remove the custom argument and replace one line reading the argument; see the adapted example in my answer.

Comment: @hoefling perfect. I was missing the config.option.keyword knowledge. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A slight modification of the example in [Control skipping of tests according to command line option](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#control-skipping-of-tests-according-to-command-line-option):

```
# conftest.py

import pytest


def pytest_collection_modifyitems(config, items):
    keywordexpr = config.option.keyword
    markexpr = config.option.markexpr
    if keywordexpr or markexpr:
        return  # let pytest handle this

    skip_mymarker = pytest.mark.skip(reason='mymarker not selected')
    for item in items:
        if 'mymarker' in item.keywords:
            item.add_marker(skip_mymarker)
```

Example tests:

```
import pytest


def test_not_marked():
    pass


@pytest.mark.mymarker
def test_marked():
    pass
```

Running the tests with the marker:

```
$ pytest -v -k mymarker
...
collected 2 items / 1 deselected / 1 selected
test_spam.py::test_marked PASSED
...
```

Or:

```
$ pytest -v -m mymarker
...
collected 2 items / 1 deselected / 1 selected
test_spam.py::test_marked PASSED
...
```

Without the marker:

```
$ pytest -v
...
collected 2 items

test_spam.py::test_not_marked PASSED
test_spam.py::test_marked SKIPPED
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of explicitly say "not marker" at pytest invocation, you can add following to pytest.ini

```
[pytest]
addopts = -m "not marker"
```